# How to install php 8 in wampserver?

Tags: php, wampserver

I am trying to install PHP 8 in wampserver, and I am following the tutorial in the official wampserver forum, but PHP 8 does not work. it shows the following error.

```
This PHP version 8.0.2 doesn't seem to be compatible with your actual Apache Version.

c:/wamp64/bin/php/php8.0.2/php8apache2_4.dll does not exist.
```

how do I solve this problem and install php8 in wampaserver?
[image]

**Information**

- windows 10 build 19042
- wampserver 3.2.3
- apache 2.4.46
- mysql 8.0.21

---

This is the page where I downloaded php8 https://windows.php.net/qa/

This is the tutorial I was using http://forum.wampserver.com/read.php?2,159568

Comment: WAMPServer now support PHP8. **It has since it was OFFICIALLY Released.** That tutorial was written to install PRE-RELEASE versions of PHP8. Its simple, go to the WAMPServer repo on SourceFroge OR [the backup repo](https://wampserver.aviatechno.net/?lang=en)  which is easier to navigate. Then download the ADDON you want. They are click and install ADDON's

Comment: If you had read that tutorial properly, it stated that that was for installing PHP8.0.0 Alpha release.

Comment: When downloading php8 you should download the Thread Safe version, that's the one containing php8apache2_4.dll

Comment: Please share more details. Why not upgrade WAMPServer properly?

Answer (score 32):

Capture PHP exiting Add-on in browser hitting in the vm/server with server/vm ip

Backup the Exiting WAMP Server 3.0.0 folder in C:/wamp64 and copy it into any local directory

## Upgrade WAMP Server 2.5/3.0.0 to the latest version 3.2.3

download and install as admin on the below link

https://wampserver.aviatechno.net/files/updates/wampserver2.5_x64_update_3.0.3.exe

Again upgrade to the latest version using below link

https://wampserver.aviatechno.net/files/updates/wampserver3_x86_x64_update3.2.5.exe

install visual c++ below

https://wampserver.aviatechno.net/files/vcpackages/vcredist_2019_x64.exe

Now Download and install php 8.0.6 Version on below link
https://wampserver.aviatechno.net/files/php/wampserver3_x64_addon_php8.0.6.exe

once successfully installation Apache will fail because of the latest PHP  version to overcome these install the latest APACHE WAMP in below link
https://wampserver.aviatechno.net/files/apache/wampserver3_x64_addon_apache2.4.48.exe

Now to Click WAMP icon in-tray icon and click refresh and start all the services and change Apache and PHP to the latest version which we installed.

if the user required to install MySQL version  8.0.24 then download and install below link

https://wampserver.aviatechno.net/files/mysql/wampserver3_x64_addon_mysql8.0.24.exe

if phpmyadmin show incompatibility then install the latest version of PHPMYADMIN as below link

https://wampserver.aviatechno.net/files/apps/wampserver3_x86_x64_phpmyadmin5.1.1.exe

### Reference Link

https://wampserver.aviatechno.net/?lang=en#mysql_versions