# How to upgrade php version in wamp for windows 10?

Tags: php, wamp, php-8

I have wamp 3.1.3, which has php 7.0.29. No I want to install php 8.
How come it will be possible. Please help.

I have tried on youtube abd google and tried some of the solutions, but they wont work.

Comment: Related ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66078991

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to install php 8 in wampserver?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66078991/how-to-install-php-8-in-wampserver)